# ksh script variables run differently in nohup

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a script called cmdtst_multi.ksh and when I run it like this:

```
. ./cmdtst_multi.ksh
```

I have a varible that gets populated like this;

```
treeLvls=$(td_query {})

echo "num of tree lvls:" $treeLvls
##gives back num of tree lvls: 4

treeLvlsSQL=$(for i in {1..$treeLvls}
    do 
    echo ",NULL as LVL$i" 
    done)

echo "tree sql:" $treeLvlsSQl
#gives back tree sql: ,NULL as LVL1 ,NULL as LVL2 ,NULL as LVL3 ,NULL as LVL4
```

it runs fine

but when I run it like this:

```
nohup cmdtst_multi.ksh > prcsstst.log &
```

the treeLvlsSQl comes out like this in the log file, which is not correct:

```
tree sql: ,NULL as LVL{1.. ,NULL as LVL4}
```

why do the variables seem to run differently?

Comment: Could the problem be that `nohup` doesn't run the script with `ksh` but with something else?

Comment: Start your script with `#!/bin/ksh` and see if Jonathan is right.
Does your ksh support the `for i in {1..5}` construction !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is this difference has something to do with the seemingly innocuous sourcing operator(`.`) or the current directory operator(`./`) at the beginning of your script.

1. `nohup` - is no hangup to make the process not to hangup when the
   user log outs
2. `> prcsstst.log &` - redirects to log file and backgrounds the
   process

which rules out them as contenders for the difference in output.

Please try the nohup with sourcing operator like below:

```
nohup ksh93 -c ". ./cmdtst_multi.ksh" > prcsstst.log
```

`.` and `./` are important `.` implies sourcing the current shell which prevents spawning a separate child shell with new set of environment variables and `./` implies the script in `.` (current directory) is executed instead of some other script with the same name defined in `$PATH`.

Edit: As Jonathan Leffler points out in his comment, this could also be because `KSH` not being used by `nohup` (`KSH` is not the default shell perhaps?) which might explain why the KSH's `FOR` syntax worked initially when sourced(`.`) from current shell(`KSH`?) but not the second time around(some other type of shell).

Comment: so when I run it like that...I get an error saying that nohup can't run the "." command...I did chmod 755 on my file, shoudl that be enough?

Comment: Sorry about that. Looks like `nohup` expects the first argument to be a filename. Also, nohup and `.` doesn't go together as `nohup` will spawn a new shell anyways. I have edited the command which is not tested as I don't have the shell here with me. The edited command ,if it works would still spawn a new shell which would defeat the purpose of sourcing. Atleast you can be sure it was executed by `Ksh` and not some other shell.